# PHP check boxes and URL rewriting

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hope someone can help me with my code. i am using rewritten URL's and have this piece of code on a form. When the page first loads mypage.htm, the type_24 checkbox get's checked by default. If they check the type_12 box, i want the type_24 box to uncheck.

My problem is, if i check the type_12 box, the page refreshes and both the type_12 and type_24 boxes are checked.. which is not what i want. I think it's because i'm reloading my rewritten URL in my action because it works fine if i just have php file as the action.

Any ideas how i can fix my code so that it only has the type_12 checked when i check the type_24 box?

```
<form name="frmrefresh" id="frmrefresh" method="post" action="mypage.htm">

<input type="checkbox" name="type_12" id="type_12" <?php if(isset($_POST['type_12']) &&    $_POST['type_12']=="12"){?> checked="checked"<?php }?> value="12"   onClick="uncheck24(this);" /> <label>12</label> 

<input type="checkbox" name="type_24" id="type_24" <?php if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!=''){?>checked="checked"<?php }?><?php if(isset($_POST['month_24']) && $_POST['type_24']=="24"){?> checked="checked"<?php }?> value="24" onClick="uncheck12(this);"/> <label>24 Months</label>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['id'];?>" />
</form>
```

In the header i have the functions:

```
function uncheck12(obj)
    {
    if (obj.checked == true)
        {
             document.getElementById("type_12").checked = false;
             document.frmrefresh.submit();
        }
}

function uncheck24(obj)
{
        if (obj.checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("type_24").checked = false;
            document.frmrefresh.submit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of remarks:

- Consider using radio buttons instead of checkboxes
- I think you mean `isset($_POST['type_24'])` instead of `isset($_POST['month_24'])`

As to your problem, I bet your rewrite rule is something like:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage.htm$ mypage.php?id=5
```

This means that when the form gets submitted via POST, PHP will still set the `$_GET['id']` variable for you since it's in the query string. And since you check the '24' option whenever `$_GET['id']` is set, the second checkbox will always get checked.
To fix this you could consider adding the check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'`:

```
<form name="frmrefresh" id="frmrefresh" method="post" action="mypage.htm">
<input type="checkbox" name="type_12" id="type_12" <?php if(isset($_POST['type_12']) &&    $_POST['type_12']=="12"){?> checked="checked"<?php }?> value="12"   onClick="uncheck24(this);" /> <label>12</label> 
<input type="checkbox" name="type_24" id="type_24" <?php if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!='' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){?>checked="checked"<?php }?><?php if(isset($_POST['type_24']) && $_POST['type_24']=="24"){?> checked="checked"<?php }?> value="24" onClick="uncheck12(this);"/> <label>24 Months</label>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['id'];?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks so much for your help. one issue though, when the page refreshes, and i do this check        
if(isset($_REQUEST['type_24']) && $_REQUEST['type_24']=='24')    it still thinks the type_24 is still checked even though on screen it looks unchecked? any ideas why? thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with 'it still thinks the type_24 is still checked'? Where and how do you see this?